# Insert into a table on the basis of condition in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table named 'Student' with columns `Name`, `Role`, `Class` and `Subject`.

I have another table named 'StudentClass' with columns `Name` and `Class`. I have to insert `Name` and `Class` columns of 'StudentClass' table from 'Student' table if the `Name` and his corresponding `Class` do not exist in the 'StudentClass' table. If `Name` exist in the 'StudentClass' table but its corresponding `Class` value is different for that row, then update the `Class` value for that row in 'StudentClass' table

I can't simply truncate the 'StudentClass' table and insert `Name` and `Class` from 'Student' table because I have keep track of any change made in the 'StudentClass' table.

So is there any mySQL query which inserts `Name` and `Class` from 'Student' table into 'StudentClass' table if the `Name` and its corresponding `Class` do not exist in 'StudentClass' table else update the row if `Name` exist but its corresponding `Class` value is different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO StudentClass (Name, Class)
SELECT Name, Class FROM Student AS S
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM StudentClass AS SC
                    WHERE SC.Name = S.Name AND SC.Class=S.Class);
```

You can find out more about EXISTS and NOT EXISTS [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html).

Answer (score 0):

The query posted by you worked only for inserting new entries. I does not provide the update function. So I modified the your query and added an update query with the insert query which solved my issue.

```
INSERT INTO StudentClass (Name, Class)
SELECT Name, Class FROM Student AS S
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM StudentClass AS SC
                    WHERE SC.Name = S.Name);


UPDATE StudentClass SC INNER JOIN Student S ON SC.Name = S.Name 
      SET SC.Class = S.Class WHERE SC.Class != S.Class
```

Thanks for help